# Spring templateResolver configure

Tags: java, spring

I have problem with correct configure templateResolver. When i try to get default page, its work fine. When i try go to the page with /someAddress i get

```
 template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.javapointers.controllers"/>
<bean id="templateResolver"
      class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5"/>
</bean>
<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver"/>
</bean>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/"/>
```

HomeController

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewHome(){
    return "test";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(){
    return "login";
}
```

Does anyone know the correct configure?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem. In my app was another beans configuration in java class.